# Update Structure Group Metadata with Core Service

Tags: core-service

I have a new namespace for my Structure Group metadata schema and I want to update all my Structure Groups using this metadata schema to the use the new namespace.  I am using [Elena's script here](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-projects/source/browse/).

However, I have an error when trying to save a Structure Group.  I want to use client.Update(data, ReadOptions) where data is the Metadata XML of the StructureGroup.  However, it fails even when I try not updating anything, and just getting and savign the same content to the item.  Here is my code and below my error.  I have no idea how to get the extra info the core service wants in the xml so I can simply replace the namespace on the Structure Group metadata.

This also occurs with a Page as well.

XSD:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="uuid:68785a26-2757-4cb0-9747-5224ec9e3215" xmlns:tcmi="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/Instance" xmlns:category="tcm:0-9-1/Categories.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="uuid:68785a26-2757-4cb0-9747-5224ec9e3215">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/Instance" schemaLocation="cm_xml_inst.xsd"></xsd:import>
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="tcm:9-7887-8"></xsd:include>
  <xsd:import namespace="tcm:0-9-1/Categories.xsd" schemaLocation="tcm:0-9-1/Categories.xsd"></xsd:import>
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="tcm:9-7628-8"></xsd:include>
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:appinfo>
      <tcm:Labels xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
        <tcm:Label ElementName="seo" Metadata="true">Search Engine Optimisation</tcm:Label>
        <tcm:Label ElementName="theme" Metadata="true">Theme</tcm:Label>
        <tcm:Label ElementName="header" Metadata="true">Header</tcm:Label>
        <tcm:Label ElementName="sections" Metadata="true">Page sections</tcm:Label>
        <tcm:Label ElementName="footer" Metadata="true">Footer</tcm:Label>
      </tcm:Labels>
    </xsd:appinfo>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:element name="Metadata">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="seo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="seo">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
              <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"></tcm:ExtensionXml>
              <tcm:EmbeddedSchema xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:9-7628-8" xlink:title="Search Engine Optimization Metadata"></tcm:EmbeddedSchema>
            </xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="theme" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="category:section-homepage-themes">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
              <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"></tcm:ExtensionXml>
              <tcm:Size xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">1</tcm:Size>
              <tcm:listtype xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">select</tcm:listtype>
            </xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="header" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="tcmi:SimpleLink">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
              <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"></tcm:ExtensionXml>
              <tcm:linktype xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">ComponentLink</tcm:linktype>
              <tcm:AllowMultimediaLinks xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">false</tcm:AllowMultimediaLinks>
              <tcm:AllowedTargetSchemas xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
                <tcm:TargetSchema xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:9-5877-8" xlink:title="Page Header"></tcm:TargetSchema>
              </tcm:AllowedTargetSchemas>
            </xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="sections" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tcmi:SimpleLink">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
              <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"></tcm:ExtensionXml>
              <tcm:linktype xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">ComponentLink</tcm:linktype>
              <tcm:AllowMultimediaLinks xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">false</tcm:AllowMultimediaLinks>
              <tcm:AllowedTargetSchemas xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
                <tcm:TargetSchema xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:9-5880-8" xlink:title="Page Section"></tcm:TargetSchema>
                <tcm:TargetSchema xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:9-5872-8" xlink:title="CTA Collection"></tcm:TargetSchema>
              </tcm:AllowedTargetSchemas>
            </xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="footer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="footer">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
              <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"></tcm:ExtensionXml>
              <tcm:EmbeddedSchema xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:9-7887-8" xlink:title="Simple Page Footer"></tcm:EmbeddedSchema>
            </xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Error Message

```
  > > XML validation error. Reason: The required attribute
    > > 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink:href' is missing..
    > 
    > "<Metadata
    > xmlns=\"uuid:68785a26-2757-4cb0-9747-5224ec9e3215\"><header><title>SG
    > title..</title></header></Metadata>"
```

Code:

```
CoreServiceClient client = new CoreServiceClient("basicHttp_2012");
string userName = "robertc";
string password = "pass";
var credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
{
    credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
}
client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = credentials;

ReadOptions readOptions = new ReadOptions();

string sg = "tcm:10-24482-4";
RepositoryLocalObjectData data = (RepositoryLocalObjectData)client.Read(sg, readOptions);
string meta = data.Metadata;
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(meta);
string metadata = data.Metadata;                
data.Metadata = metadata;
try
{
    client.Update(data, readOptions);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

XSD:

Comment: Can you add what data.Metadata currently contains to the question?

Comment: Are you able to update the metadata using Tridion Explorer? also what kind of fields are Header and Title?

Comment: It might be the case that in your schema, text field was changed from text to link, or something like this. Could you please post XSD of your schema?

Comment: It is possible the field type was changed.  Another developer worked on it and has been making the changes to the schemas, and content porting them(!). I tested data.Metadata with empty fields and also some filled out.  Same results.  I am able to update through CME.

Comment: Sorry, it is not possible to save with the GUI.  Hmmm

Comment: It looks like you don't have the xlink import in your namespace.  Off the top of my head I don't remember where it is but you should have something similar to  
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/Instance" schemaLocation="cm_xml_inst.xsd"></xsd:import>
but says xmlns:xlink instead of xmlns:tcm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code was OK.  However, a linked Multimedia Schema had an incorrect namespace and this was the root cause of the error.